# Failed to set date for calendar in alarm manager

Tags: android, android-studio, alarmmanager, android-calendar

I am using Android Studio and Java language to set alarm manager. If I do not set the date, the function is correct, but if I set the date, the alert will not be played or it will be executed incorrectly.
This is my code :

intent = new Intent(this, BootBroadcastReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
this.getApplicationContext(), 280192, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

```
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();

    Calendar calendar = (Calendar) calendar2.clone();
     calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    

    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1400);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 9);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,27);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 9);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTime().getTime(), pendingIntent);
```

Please help friends

Comment: I forgot, my history is based on my country, Iran

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
intent = ...
pendingIntent = ...

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2021);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 12);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 19);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I also added these codes, but it still did not work!